# Way to check how many minutes users are using your app

Tags: android

I have not installed any google analytics or anything else on my android app. Is there any way to check how much time individual users are spending on android app through android market or through admob? Any way without installing third party code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just start a timer thread every time your app is started/resumed/etc?

You'd need to keep track of the total time in persistent storage, perhaps having both a running cumulative total, and a "this activation" time, if you're interested in that sort of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this code on each of the activities in my app.

```
onResume(){
    startTime = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
}


onPause(){
  endTime = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  long usage_time = endTime.getTimeInMillis()-startTime.getTimeInMillis();
  addTimeToTotalUsage(usage_time);
}
```

In this case `addTimeToTotalUsage()` would be some method where you persistently store an accumulated value of total usage time.

Comment: Isnt here any way without adding any code to check that? Android market or admod does not capture that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's extra instrumentation of code which invariably means there will addition resource consumption (battery, processing power, etc.). They're not going to add universal instrumentation like that unless pretty much every one the functionality it's adding (i.e. everyone wants to know battery usage and network usage).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at flurry: http://www.flurry.com/